# UITableView + UIWebView within UIScrollView

Tags: uitableview, uiscrollview, storyboard, swift

I'm struggling with wrapping my head around using UITableView with UIWebView within UIScrollView. The interface I'm trying to build consist of a header (containing a few labels, always the same size), UIWebView (can be any height, I'm scaling it dependently on the content) and a UITableView (also can have any number of elements). I want user to scroll through the whole content like he would be scrolling through one page.

I realize that Apple doesn't recommend using UITableView or UIWebView within UIScrollView. However, I'm having a hard time to think about some workaround.

Is it possible to get the desired effect done the way I'm trying to do it right now? If not, what would be the cleanest or at least working way of doing it?

(I'm currently using Xcode 6 beta 3 / swift)

[image]

Comment: Same problem here mate! I need a scrollable list of tiles with custom information and different types of content...

Answer (score 0):

You can set your `UIScrollView`'s `contentSize.height` to the sum of your `UITableView`'s `contentSize.height` and the height of your `UIWebView`'s content.

To get it, just add this to your `ViewController` after setting it as your `UIWebView`'s delegate:

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView!)  {
    let output = webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("document.body.offsetHeight;")
    let contentHeight = (output as NSString).floatValue
}
```

Then, you just have to set the frame height of your `tableView` and `webView` to their content's height and place them correctly in the scroll view.

Hope this will help,

Comment: getting a type error on this trying to convert Float to CGFloat